# What are the consequences of not rinsing hermetic lentils prior to use?

Tags: lentils

There are these hermetic boiled green lentils that I've been eating for a decade. They are great in salads, etc.
[image]

The text on these boxes is in Scandinavian languages. It basically says, among other things, that they are ready to eat, boiled green lentils, and that they should be rinsed with water before use.

That means one should drain the liquid they are immersed in and rinse with clean water.

[image]

For all these years, I never read the text on the box, and consequently never rinsed them. I just drained most of the liquid and used them as they were.

What would be the potential consequences of not rinsing them?

Comment: related, https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/11903/should-i-rinse-canned-beans-before-using-them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only consequence is that you will eat the liquid in which they were. They will taste different with it. Also, if you cook them, they may be more prone to sticking, because of starch and other stuff sticking to the surface. This is not an issue in salads, though.

You probably already know the consequences anyway, since you have been eating them that way already.

Comment: So this liquid is not bad for health or anything?

Comment: "Bad for health" is off topic here. It certainly won't give you acute food poisoning, but beyond that, it is all speculation.